# Loop url links and save as pdf files in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pdfkit

Given a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
             projectCode                                                url
0  FCZZZZCQ2021020200921  https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/FCZZZZCQ2021020200921
1        GR2021BJ1000351  https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/GR2021BJ1000351
2        GR2021QD1000030  https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/GR2021QD1000030
3        GR2021BJ1000186  https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/GR2021BJ1000186
4    FCZZCQ2020123011487  https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/FCZZCQ2020123011487
```

I want to use `pdfkit` package save each `url` link as pdf file, and use `projectCode` as file name:

```
import pdfkit
import pandas as pd

data = []
urls =  df.url.tolist()
for url_link in urls:
    pdfkit.from_url(url, 'out.pdf')
```

How could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: is you are reading from pdf file or csv file just want to confirm

Comment: also how you created dataframe please do insert that code also so it will help solving issue fast

Comment: I read from `xlsx` format excel file @M_x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `zip` the columns to use it:

```
for a, url in zip(df['projectCode'], df['url']):
    pdfkit.from_url(url, f'{a}.pdf')
```